# Get webform values in page which is action for this webform

Tags: webforms

I have created a form using webform in Drupal 6. I have set a action URL like `node/15` a new node. When form is submitted it will be redirect this node. I want to display all values which are filled by user at this page. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter` and add your custom submit handler.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_form().
     */
    function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'WEBFORM_ID') {
            $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_webfrom_submit';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implements webform custom handler
     */
    function custom_webfrom_submit($form, &$form_state){
        //get the values here $form_state['values']
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. can you please tell me where i will use this code . i am redirecting my from at node/6 after submission

Comment: Use in your custom module. Tutorial for [custom module development](https://drupal.org/node/206753)

Comment: By the way thanks for your reply. i was asking for any solution in the node page using admin and i got the solution. enable php filter module . edit the page where form is redirecting after submission and add <?php

module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$sid = $_REQUEST['sid'];
$submission = webform_get_submissions(array('sid' => $sid));
$nid = $submission[$sid]->nid;
 
$web_submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$node = node_load($nid);

print $output = webform_submission_render($node, $web_submission, NULL, 'html');
 
?>

Comment: Adding PHP code in your database by enabling this PHP filter can cause you to get extremely unsafe sitewise. So my suggestion is to add in the custom module only.

Comment: Okay. so custom_webfrom_submit function result will be displayed on the page which i will use as action page for this webform . am i right ?

Comment: Yes your right, you will get all the values submitted by user.